# Удалить код языка из ссылки через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

На сайте есть локализация и код языка в url - если сайт переключили на английский, соответственно site.ru/en/some-path.

Но, с точки зрения SEO ссылка sute.ru/ru/some-path считается дублем, если язык сайта по-умолчанию и ссылка без кода языка, типа: site.ru/some-path.

Вопрос: Как сделать, что бы именно при site.ru/ru перенаправлять на site.ru/ - с сохранением путей, если есть.

Мой вариант, который не работает вообще:

```
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Платформа Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы убрать дубликаты для SEO существует тег LINK специального вида:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/en/product/" />
```

URL которого, должен быть каноническим для всех дубликатов.

И независимо от того, какой реальный URL будет у страницы:

```
https://example.com/product/
https://example.com/en/product/
https://example.com/en/category/product/
http://example.com/en/product/
https://www.example.com/product/
```

для SEO будет отобран его канонический URL.

Comment: Мой вопрос не в этом заключается, ответ ваш тоже мне Америку не открыл. Беда в том, что уже есть проиндексированные страницы в Google - их нужно заредиректить на страницу без /ru/ - в случае русской версии сайта, а /en и /fr,  оставить как есть.

Comment: Мой ответ предлагает решение лучше. Во первых, redirect - очень плохо для SEO. Во вторых, что мешает взять текущий URL, убрать из него `ru/` и прописать его в `canonical`? Тем более у вас там целый фреймворк, с библиотекой, для работы с URL.

Comment: Так задачу поставили в Netpeak.